# Mysql 8 - load geojson values using load data infile

Tags: geojson, load-data-infile, mysql-8.0

How can I import geojson values in a mysql column using load data infile? for example I have a file as follows (simplified for brevity):

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection", "features": [
    {"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":
       [
          [
            [31.287890625000017,-22.40205078125001],
            [31.429492187500017,-22.298828125],
            [32.37109375,-21.33486328125001]
          ]
       ] },"properties":{"NAME":"Zimbabwe"}
    },
    {"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":
       [
          [
            [30.39609375,-15.64306640625],
            [30.3505859375,-15.349707031250006],
            [30.231835937500023,-14.990332031250006]
          ]
       ]},"properties":{"NAME":"Zambia"}
    }
  ]
}
```

Currently when I do the following:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/Downloads/countries.geojson' INTO TABLE countries  (geo_json);
```

I get error:

```
Invalid JSON text: "Invalid value." at position 2668 in value for column 'countries.geo_json'
```

How can I load each feature into a table which has a json column called geo_json. Then I want to extract the name for each feature and add to a name column?